# Passing values into another class, also having trouble understanding ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ok. This may sound bare bones basic stuff here, but I need help. Come from a Java background, so appreciate it if you bear with me. I'll break my problem into a more granular form for everyone to understand. So I have a class that calls a database and it essentially grabs a user key. So I need that user key to be shared through a number of classes. So, my instinct tells me to make getters and setters for the variable. So here's the function I am talking about:

```
-(void) getUserKey{

    NSString * showKey = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0)];

    //Setter for showKey 
    [self showKey:showKey];
    //For experimenting, I attempt to set a property and try to access it.  
    self.SHOWKEY = showKey;

}
```

Here are my getters and setters for the key returned from the database.

```
  - (void) showKey:(NSString *)n{

    NSLog(@"%@",n);
    globalShowKey = n;

}


- (NSString*) showPath {

    return globalShowKey;
}
```

Now here's where I am having trouble when I call this method that assembles a file path together for other classes, my global show key is all the sudden nil.

```
-(NSString *)globalShowPath{

    NSString *mainDbPath = [PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:CLIENT_KEY];
   //Nil
    NSString * showKey = [self showPath];

    NSString *subDirectory = [mainDbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:showKey];

    return subDirectory;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to learn from this simple mistake! Ugh!

Here's my header for reference:

```
AppDelegate.h

{    
     NSString * globalShowKey;
}

@property (strong, readwrite) NSString *SHOWKEY;
-(NSString *)globalShowPath;
- (NSString*) showPath;
```

Comment: What exactly is nil here? Are all of these methods in the same class? (By the way, a suggestion: try to adhere to a common coding/indentation style; in addition to making your code more maintainable, your question will be much more readable.)

Comment: I would recommend reading this guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Comment: Correct. All the methods are in the same class. I am calling the globalShowPath in other classes. The showKey string is nil when I call the getter. I know it sets the setter just fine.

Comment: Your method names are very nonstandard. In fact it seems like you have very little reason to write custom getters and setters; you can probably just use the compiler-synthesized property getter and setter.

Comment: @jtbandes could you provide an example?

Comment: You can't set a value in one instance of a class and have it magically appear in another instance of the class.  Can't do it in Java, can't do it in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an instance of the class you need to pass data to, you can just set the relevant variable in the .h as

```
@property NSString *profileKey;
```

for example. then to access:

```
[myObject profileKey];
```

and to set, do

```
myObject.profileKey = @"my new string";
```

Objective-c doesn't really make use of getters or setters, but rather does the above. It can be a rough life transitioning over from Java but Objective-c is much better.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I still get nil on the property I set. I then accessed it through the method parenthesis you suggested.